# Creating Graphical User Interface in R

Tags: r, matlab, user-interface, data-analysis

Currently I am carrying out data analysis in R. Ultimately I want to create a GUI that can give the summary of the analysis and the main plots. Does anyone know if I can use R to create the interface? If not, do you know if I can combine MATLAB (for GUI) and R?

I appreciate your cooperation.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can. (And that's the best answer anyone could give with the level of detail you provide).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You might have wondered why I asked a vague question but I have a reason. I tried to find out by myself if it is possible but the only thing what I got was not about creating GUI rather the GUI for R, like Rcmdr. Could you please suggest me to read something that could help a beginner? Thanks once again!

Comment: I would suggest looking into [rpanel](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpanel/index.html), which is built on tcltk, and [RGtk2](http://www.ggobi.org/rgtk2/), which is built on GTK+.

Comment: You're welcome. Since this is what you were looking for, I added this as an answer so that it can be accepted (and thus removed from the unanswered questions page).

Comment: Is making a nice report (in pdf, html) off the table?

Comment: See edit: I *strongly* recommend Sweave.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking into [rpanel](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpanel/index.html), which is built on tcltk, and [RGtk2](http://www.ggobi.org/rgtk2/), which is built on GTK+.

ETA: In response to your comment about making PDF/HTML reports with R: I would *strongly* recommend [Sweave](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/Sweave/) which embeds R into LaTeX. It's powerful and capable of making very well-formatted reports.

Answer (score 2):

This package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ProgGUIinR/index.html has some code for making guis as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

[Rcommander](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcmdr/index.html), [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/) and, if you are using linux, RKWard (http://rkward.sourceforge.net/) provide some GUI elements for plotting and statistical analysis. That may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I want to create a GUI for a specific type of dataset myself not use GUI.